# 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid database' Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I've encountered following error. I don't know why. My XCode version is 7.2. Please help me how to solve that issue.

Here is just copy defauly.realm.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.realm"];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath] == NO) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"realm"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:txtPath error:&error];
}
```

Here is error log I got.

```
2016-04-12 10:47:04.791 APACRS[1190:84550] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid database'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001089d0e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108449deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   APACRS                              0x0000000105b1192d _Z18RLMSetErrorOrThrowP7NSErrorPU15__autoreleasingS0_ + 176
    3   APACRS                              0x0000000105b02f56 -[RLMRealm initWithPath:key:readOnly:inMemory:dynamic:error:] + 2409
    4   APACRS                              0x0000000105b037bc +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:key:readOnly:inMemory:dynamic:schema:error:] + 595
    5   APACRS                              0x0000000105b033c4 +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:] + 51
    6   APACRS                              0x0000000105b03330 +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] + 69
    7   APACRS                              0x0000000105adb34d +[RLMObject allObjects] + 38
    8   APACRS                              0x0000000105a2593b +[WebImages getWebData] + 43
    9   APACRS                              0x0000000105a17d9b -[HomeViewController initController] + 171
    10  APACRS                              0x0000000105a17ba9 -[HomeViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106ba5f98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106ba62e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106bf88b0 -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 194
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106b7d0aa -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 59
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106b79438 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 95
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106a1b4a2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106a2ec01 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106a3aaf3 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088fc367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088fc2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088f1f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088f1828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ad8ead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000106a0f610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  APACRS                              0x00000001059f591f main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001093af92d start + 1
)
```

Comment: That code looks fine to me! The only thing I can possibly think is the realm file you're copying from the resources folder might be damaged some way. Can you confirm that it still opens on its own? You can use the Realm Browser app on the Mac App Store to try and open it.

Comment: I can open Realm Browser to open that database. It's because of conflict between Xcode version and Realm version?

Comment: Really?? Hmm, that's really strange then. What version of Realm are you running? Are you on the latest version in your app and was the same version used to create that default realm? I don't believe there should be a problem because of Xcode's version.